# HDD not mounting on bootup with fstab

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, fstab

We have a removeable HDD caddy (single drive caddy) for backups, with three HDDs- Only 1 hdd is used at any one time.

I can / sometimes manually mount the drives by typing

> sudo mount -a

followed by

> sudo lsblk --fs

to check if mounted

But I cannot get them to mount with fstab on boot.

```
    #Hot backupdisk1
    UUID=5C5D14B8044A6AA1   /media/backupdisk  ntfs  auto,nofail  0 2
    #Hot backupdisk2
    UUID=1447ECF46C1947D4   /media/backupdisk  ntfs  auto,nofail  0 2
    #Hot backupdisk3
    UUID=77886B755AE0BC84   /media/backupdisk  ntfs  auto,nofail  0 2
```

Any pointers please, I've run out if web to search :(

Additional Bumf

> sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9B032955-FA89-4C7D-93F6-0EC54D2AE8E3
```

> sudo blkid

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="77886B755AE0BC84" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="061a788c-5618-4169-89e6-c0015a1b9365"
```

Comment: A clue maybe? I tried "/dev/sdc1 /media/backupdisk ntfs-3g defaults,nofail 0 0" but got Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: I have a poor workaround  - editing the fstab to "/dev/sdc1 /media/backupdisk ntfs   defaults,nofail 0 0" and hoping that the backup drive is always sdc1

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your configuration, you need 3 mount points for the drives.  All drives need their own mount points or what happens is that the first one will mount, then the second one will override it, then the third will override as well.

Rename your mount point:

```
sudo mv /media/backupdisk /media/backupdisk1
```

Then create 2 more mount points:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/backupdisk2
sudo mkdir -p /media/backupdisk3
```

Then fix your mounts in `/etc/fstab` like so:

```
#Hot backupdisk1
UUID=5C5D14B8044A6AA1   /media/backupdisk1  ntfs  defaults,nofail  0 0
#Hot backupdisk2
UUID=1447ECF46C1947D4   /media/backupdisk2  ntfs  defaults,nofail  0 0
#Hot backupdisk3
UUID=77886B755AE0BC84   /media/backupdisk3  ntfs  defaults,nofail  0 0
```

Save and reboot.  Now you should see all three as separate mounts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheers Terrance, but I would have thought not! My caddy only has one bay! Only 1 or no hdd can be present.

Comment: @Floggedhorse Is it partitioned into 3 then?  If so, each partition needs it's own mount too.

Comment: No three separate drives,each with a single partition 1TB, one drive in caddy, 2nd drive allowed moved from building to building, third drive kept offsite. Only one drive is ever in the caddy/server (Hence the "nofail")

Comment: @Floggedhorse Ah, OK.  As long as only one drive is used at a time, it should be fine for the same mount point to all.  My personal preference would be to have separate mounts just to leave confusion behind, but either way should be fine.